# How to check if SuperObject is valid?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2010, superobject

When creating a SuperObject from a string, it might happen that the string is no valid JSon.
Unfortunately the command SO doesn't raise an exception in that case.
I end up with a object where I THINK I can store data in, but the "stored" data goes nowhere and is lost.

example:

```
 MySo:=SO('{}');
 MySO.S['ok']:='test';
 Memo1.Lines.Add(MySO.AsJSon(True, False));

 MySo:=SO('');
 MySO.S['fail']:='mimimi';
 Memo1.Lines.Add(MySO.AsJSon(True, False));  // returns '""' ??!??
```

How can I check if the string was converted successfully into a valid and working SuperObject?

Comment: Use `Validate`:  https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject/blob/master/tests/test_validate.dpr

Comment: What would be a proper syntax for validate? In the sample even the string "5" is a valid JSon. But if I create a JSon that way, I can't store anything in there. That's my problem described above.

Answer (score 1):

whorsyourdaddy's comment pointed into the right direction.

To be able to store INTO a JSon you need a stObject. You can check for that this way:

```
 if not MySo.IsType(stObject) then raise....
```

Comment: In case of an invalid json the result is nil! This test results then in an access violation.
`if (MySo= nil) or (not MySo.IsType(stObject)) then`
is the way to go